# Why is my water pressure low after new system installed?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, well

Well pump, bladder tank, and pressure switch all installed in the summer. Switch is set to 30/50 but keeps falling to low20s/50 psi. The bladder tank is not leaking, 28psi when emptied. Also readjusted  pressure switch to 30/50, then the psi dropped. We've looked for leaks. How do we restore better water pressure?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a couple of things.  First of all, lets take the simplest, it could be a defective or miss-calibrated pressure switch. These aren't exactly rocket science and it could simply be defective.

Next, harder to solve, but could be:  Does your well produce enough water to maintain the pressure you want during usage? Maybe at times you are "pumping air" if the water level in the well drops below the pump.

Next: Does your pump have the capacity to maintain pressure during heavier usage? Any changes to your water usage, such as a new sprinkler system or fancy, multi head showers?

I know I'm asking a couple of questions in my "answer", but it would have been too long for a comment.